# In discord.js, how could i create a command that displays the avatar of a user tagged, or if not tagged - my avatar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on("message", msg => {
      if (msg.content === `${prefix}pfp`) {
        var users = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        msg.channel.send(users.displayAvatarURL());
  }
})
```

Usually, this code only sends the display of the message author's avatar, but not the person who was tagged in the command.

Comment: Isn't *.js javascript, not java?

Comment: oops! the tag is changed now, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
      if (msg.content === `${prefix}pfp`) {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        var users = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        msg.channel.send(users.displayAvatarURL());
  }
})
```

You're using `msg.content` which is the overall content of the message. If you mention someone, the content will be `${prefix}pfp <@a_user's_id>` instead of `${prefix}pfp` which will then not call the command.

Try instead to use `msg.startsWith()` like shown below:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
      if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}pfp`)) {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        var users = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        msg.channel.send(users.displayAvatarURL());
  }
})
```

This will call the function if it starts with `${prefix}pfp` rather than it containing such. Which will allow them to mention someone.

Comment: Hey, this was really helpful thank you! There is one issue, and that was when i used msg.startsWith(...). it gave the error : TypeError: msg.startsWith is not a function.
Thats why i changed it to : msg.content.startsWith(...), and it works perfectly now.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I missed that, thank you and your welcome :)